# Monitor Console.app for a string and notify when found

Tags: hard-drive, script, console

Is it possible to monitor all messages in Console.app for a string and then notify the user when this string occurs?

I have the problem that I'm getting disk I/O errors and I suspect that it's not a HDD failure, but somehow is caused by a piece of software. The only way I know that I have disk I/O errors is that I sometimes look through all the messages in the Console.app out of curiosity. Of course this does not give me real time information.
Therefore I want to receive a notification when the following message occurs in the Console:

```
07/01/2013 20:59:06 kernel  disk0s1: I/O error.
```

Is this somehow possible? It's OK if this means that Console has to be on all the time.

I'm on Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use Console.app.  Instead use Terminal.app with the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep "string you are looking for"
```

then leave that window open and you will see all matching entries in that window as you work.

Also know that when the system.log file is rotated (due to size/time) tail will stop.  you will need to restart the command.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'm looking for. Could you clarify the rotating bit? How often is the system.log rotated? Could I code into terminal that it should restart automatically as well?

Comment: @BartArondson When the log gets too long, it gets archived into a file named system.log.1.bz1, for example.

Answer (score 2):

1. `sudo /usr/bin/gem install terminal-notifier`
2. Save this script as `~/bin/logcheck` and run `chmod +x ~/bin/logcheck`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   tmp=${TMPDIR}logcheck
   [ -f $tmp ] && last=$(cat $tmp) || last=""
   found=$(grep -A-1 "^$last" /var/log/system.log | grep -F 'kernel  disk0s1: I/O error')
   [ -n "$found" ] && terminal-notifier -message "$found"
   last=$(grep -Eo '^\w{3} [ \d]\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d' /var/log/system.log | tail -n1)
   printf %s "$last" > $tmp
   ```
3. `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`, add `*/5 * * * * ~/bin/logcheck`

Comment: I get `sudo: usr/bin/gem: command not found`. I'm on 10.6.8, so that might matter. Sorry I forgot to mention it at first.

Comment: @BartArondson RubyGems has only been installed by default since 10.7. terminal-notifier doesn't work on 10.6 either, but you can use growlnotify.